# Field list in ambiguous in join with 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Very confused why this is happening since I'm naming the specific tables as `es` and `sub` that it's complaining about (and I think that's how you fix that particular issue).

I've got:
`users` `submissions_comments` `email_settings` `submissions` tables

This query gives me what I want, but I now want to join this on my `email_settings` and `submissions` table which both have a `user_id`.

```
SELECT user_id,
       submission_id,
       comment,
       users.*,
FROM submissions_comments
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id
   FROM submissions_comments
   WHERE id = 224) x ON submissions_comments.id = x.parent_id
LEFT JOIN users ON submissions_comments.user_id = users.id
```

Output:

```
       user_id: 35
 submission_id: 12
       comment: fdasadfsdadfs
            id: 35
         email: bobcobb@gmail.com
      username: bobcobb
          name: Robert Cobb
         about:
       created: 2014-03-21 20:24:57
    last_login: 2014-07-06 23:21:43
public_profile: 1
  queued_photo: 0
```

But if I try to join on another table (which has a reference to a `user_id`) I get `Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`

```
SELECT user_id,
       submission_id,
       comment,
       users.*,
       es.*,
       sub.*
FROM submissions_comments
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id
   FROM submissions_comments
   WHERE id = 224) x ON submissions_comments.id = x.parent_id
LEFT JOIN users ON submissions_comments.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN submissions sub ON x.parent_id = sub.user_id
LEFT JOIN email_settings es ON x.parent_id = es.user_id;
```

As you can tell I'm joining all of these on the user_id returned from the inner select (e.g. `x.parent_id`).

Comment: isn't it less confusing to use field names in your query than `*`?

Comment: You should have tried to search before asking. "Field list is ambigous" is easily solved by adding table name before column name _sub.user_id_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the alias to the column name:

```
SELECT sub.user_id,...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT submissions_comments.user_id,
       submissions_comments.submission_id,
       submissions_comments.comment,
       users.*,
       es.*,
       sub.*
FROM submissions_comments
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id
   FROM submissions_comments
   WHERE id = 224) x ON submissions_comments.id = x.parent_id
LEFT JOIN users ON submissions_comments.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN submissions sub ON x.parent_id = sub.user_id
LEFT JOIN email_settings es ON x.parent_id = es.user_id;
```

you need to define which user_id you are referring on the select part as well.